# Datatables - fixedHeader with scrollX

Tags: datatables

I am trying to use Datatables with fixedheader (v3) as well as enable horizontal scrolling. Attached is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/344/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({        
       searching: false,
        paging: false,
        ordering: false,
        info: false,
        fixedHeader: true,
        scrollX: true
    });

} );
```

.

When scrolling the fixedheader width doesn't align with the rest of the table. Can you help me solve this please?

Thanks

Comment: fixedHeader is not compatible with setting the scrolling - see here: https://www.datatables.net/download/compatibility

Comment: Working sample: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40362689/548473

Comment: @GKislin that is not working sample - ScrollX & FixedHeader still not possible

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 9):

Pure css solution using css sticky (not work in ie 11):
remove the fixHeader plugin
add this css

```
.dataTables_scrollHead {
  position: sticky !important;
  top: 119px;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(82, 63, 105, 0.08);
}
```

Comment: Very simple and handful solution for a datatables sticky header. Thank you!

Comment: How to make this work I don`t understand? Which class is this?

Answer (score 3):

I have read for 2 days about this, so joining all of them together, here's my contribution.

I got it figured out, hopefully this is useful for someone or help in the development as well.

My datatables is in a DIV and horizontal Scrolling enable due to huge table. When fixed header was set it was set as FIXED, and a new table is inserted at the BODY rather than inside the div.

I made it appended to the DIV instead of BODY so that the overflow rule might be inherited.

File:
dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js (search for "appendTo")
From:

```
e.table().node().cloneNode(!1)).removeAttr("id").append(f).appendTo("body")
```

To:

```
e.table().node().cloneNode(!1)).removeAttr("id").append(f).appendTo(".dataTables_scroll")
```

Now that it's appended to the the datatables-created-div, same level as dataTables_scrollHead, dataTables_scrollBody rather than stranded alone at body, whatever overflow still showing/sticking out.

File:
fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css
From:

```
table.dataTable.fixedHeader-floating{position:fixed !important}
```

To

```
table.dataTable.fixedHeader-floating{position:absolute !important}
```

or File:
fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css
From:

```
table.fixedHeader-floating{position:fixed !important;background-color:white;}
```

To

```
table.fixedHeader-floating{position:absolute !important;background-color:white;}
```

Careful of CACHE of the CSS and JS files.

Now that the floating sticky row has appeared but out of place and overflow in effect.
Have this JS running, detecting when fixedHeader-floating appears, keep adjusting them to follow the horizontal scroll and stick to the top.

```
setInterval(function(){
  if($('.fixedHeader-floating').is(':visible')){
     var myoffset = Math.round($(window).scrollTop() - $('#Detail2Container').position().top + $('.topbar').height() - 145);
     var positionleft = $('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner').position();
     $('.fixedHeader-floating').css({ 'top': myoffset, 'left': positionleft.left + 10 });
  }
}, 50); //every 50ms
```

Detail2Container is the DIV that wrap the Datatables.
I couldn't use dataTables_wrapper as reference as there are a few of them in the same page. In my page, I only one table that needs fixedHeader, if I need 2, it will be tough. But I will deal with it when the needs arise.

You could adjust the calculation according to your own design.

2 days for me to figure this out. So I feel like sharing it too.

Comment: Thanks, Your solution worked for me.
You save my life :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on my project by doing this:

```
$('#example').scroll(function() {
    if ( $(".fixedHeader-floating").is(":visible") ) {
        $(".fixedHeader-floating").scrollLeft( $(this).scrollLeft() );
    }
});
```

DataTables creates a new table as the fixedHeader when you scroll down, what I'm doing here is to detect when the user scrolls horizontally on the `$('#example')` table and then I use `scrollLeft()` on the fixedHeader to match the scroll position.

I also added this to my .css so the user won't be able to scroll on the fixedHeader table:

```
.fixedHeader-floating {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Not working for Me  can you share the working punker example

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the problem.

```
let tableParams = {
    autoWidth: false,
    // etc...
    scrollX: true,
    fixedHeader: true,
    initComplete: function(settings, json) {
        // To fix the issue of when scrolling on the X axis, the header needs also to scroll as well.
        this.find('.dataTables_scrollBody').on('scroll', function() {
            this.find('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
        });
    },
};
```

Also to hide the vertical scroll bar.

```
me.containerElement.find('.dataTables_scrollBody').css({'overflow-y': 'hidden'});
```

where `containerElement` is the parent element of the datatable element.

Answer (score 1):

Following is working to me

```
  $('.dataTables_scrollBody').on('scroll', function () {
       $('.dataTables_scrollHead', $(this).parent()).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/55670/fixed-header-with-scrollx), I was able to make it working (*issue: when FixedHeader is floating, sorting would not work*  `==>` **see update 1 below to fix it**)

**Explanations:**

1. FixedHeader (`.dataTables_scrollHeadInner`) is a different table outside of datatable (`.dataTables_scrollBody`)
2. when scrolling vertically, it will check scrolltop and set FixedHeader top accordingly.
3. when scrolling horizontally, it will scroll FixedHeader with body (`$('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft())`)

### JS

```js
// sorry - had to use global variable
// global variable for scroll-body y position
var yPositionOfScrollBody;

function adjustDatatableInnerBodyPadding(){
    let $dtScrollHeadInner = $('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner');
    let outerHeightOfInnerHeader = $dtScrollHeadInner.outerHeight(true);
    //console.log('outerHeightOfInnerHeader => ' + outerHeightOfInnerHeader);
    $('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('padding-top', outerHeightOfInnerHeader); 
}

function setFixedHeaderTop(header_pos){
    //console.log("header_pos : " + header_pos);
    $('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner').css({"top": header_pos});
}

function fixDatatableHeaderTopPosition(){
    //console.log("fixHeaderTop...");

    yPositionOfScrollBody = window.scrollY + document.querySelector('.dataTables_scrollBody').getBoundingClientRect().top;
    //console.log("yPositionOfScrollBody: " + yPositionOfScrollBody);

    setFixedHeaderTop(yPositionOfScrollBody);
}

function onDataTableInitComplete(settings, json) {

    // for vertical scolling
    yPositionOfScrollBody =  window.scrollY + document.querySelector('.dataTables_scrollBody').getBoundingClientRect().top;

    // datatable padding adjustment
    adjustDatatableInnerBodyPadding();

    // data table fixed header F5 (refresh/reload) fix
    let scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    //console.log("scrollTop => " + scrollTop);
    if(scrollTop > 1){
        let header_pos;
        if (scrollTop < yPositionOfScrollBody){
           header_pos = yPositionOfScrollBody - scrollTop;
        } else {
           header_pos = 0;
        }
        setFixedHeaderTop(header_pos);
    }

    let $dtScrollHeadInner = $('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner');
    // horizontal scrolling
    $('.dataTables_scrollBody').on('scroll', function () {

        let $dtScrollBody = $(this);

        // synchronize
        let amountOfLeftScroll = $dtScrollBody.scrollLeft();
        $dtScrollHeadInner.scrollLeft(amountOfLeftScroll);

        let scrollDiff =  $dtScrollHeadInner.scrollLeft() - amountOfLeftScroll;

        //console.log("scrollDiff: " + scrollDiff);

        if(scrollDiff < 0){
            $dtScrollHeadInner.css('left', scrollDiff);
        }else{
            //console.log("scroll back to left side");
            $dtScrollHeadInner.css('left', '');
        }

    });

    //console.log("adjusment mergin: " + yPositionScrollHeadInner);
    $(document).on('scroll', function () {
        let scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(scroll_pos <= 0){
            fixDatatableHeaderTopPosition();
        }else{
            let margin = yPositionOfScrollBody; // Adjust it to your needs
            let cur_pos = $('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner').position();
            let header_pos = cur_pos.top;
            if (scroll_pos < margin){
               header_pos = margin - scroll_pos;
            } else {
               header_pos = 0;
            }
            setFixedHeaderTop(header_pos);
        }
    });
}


$(function(){

    $("#tableId").DataTable({
        scrollX: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
        initComplete: onDataTableInitComplete,
        // ... : ...
    });
});
```

### CSS

```css
/* data table - scroll and fixed header */
table.dataTable.fixedHeader-floating {
    display: none !important;  /*Hide the fixedHeader since we dont need it*/
}

.dataTables_scrollHeadInner{
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*margin-right: 30px;*/
    background: white;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dataTables_scrollBody{
    padding-top: 2.5em;
}

div.dataTables_scrollHead table.dataTable {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

### Update 1 - sort issue fix

use `fixedHeader: false`

```js
$(function(){

    $("#tableId").DataTable({
        scrollX: true,
        fixedHeader: false,
        initComplete: onDataTableInitComplete,
        // ... : ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change 'left' but saving initial value first:

```
var initLeft = 0;

$(".dataTables_scrollBody").scroll(function () {
    if ($(".fixedHeader-floating").is(":visible")) {
        if (initLeft == 0)
            initLeft = $(".fixedHeader-floating").position().left;

        $(".fixedHeader-floating").css("left", $(this).scrollLeft() * (-1) + initLeft);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({        
       searching: true,
        paging: true,
        ordering: true,
        info: false,
        scrollY: 400,
        dom: 'Blfrtip',

    });

} );
```

Comment: Could you [edit[ your answer to offer an explanation of what you’re doing and why you prefer this over the existing, established answers?

Comment: because it is working for me

Comment: That explanation is not going to help future readers very much. Are you suggesting that the existing answers _didn't_ solve the problem for you? Is there a _key difference_ in your approach that resulted in this solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Reordering a column after initializing the datatable somehow fixed this problem for me. I hope it will work for you guys. (fixedheader version 3.3.2 jquery.dataTables version 1.13.4)

```
const table = $('#table').DataTable({
  // Datatable options
  ...
  "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
});

table.order([ 0, 'desc' ]).draw();
```