# DataTable Fixed Header Not Being Applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, html-table

I have a table using [datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/header_footer.html) plug-in. 
I'm trying to make my table header fixed, and follow this link : [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/header_footer.html)

```
$('.device-table').DataTable( {
    "fixedHeader": {
        header: true,
    },
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "Filter": false,
    "Info": false,
} );
```

I don't see the effect. I've included both js files of datatables and fixedHeader:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How would one go about and debug this?

Comment: Can you please make a quick fiddle with your code and share us the link to debug?

Comment: Did you check the jsfiddle? it doesn't work... check the console for errors

Comment: double check again? please make sure next time it really works...

Comment: Try this one : https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/s2xbf9d0/5/show/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For the `fixedHeader` plugin to work you also need the `css` file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
```

Check this update:
https://jsfiddle.net/s2xbf9d0/6/

Comment: I added your suggestion and still didn't see it. Check it out here = http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/s2xbf9d0/10/

Comment: You are messing the the styles :) remove the `height: 150px;` you have in the css and set `scrollY:  '150px'` in the `DataTable` constructor instead. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/s2xbf9d0/11/

Answer (score 6):

Your fiddle seems to be missing the `dataTables.fixedHeader` plugin as well as the `fixedHeader.dataTables` CSS file which was causing you the page from rendering properly (with the fixed headers).

**Working DEMO:** - https://jsfiddle.net/s2xbf9d0/7/

Hope this helps!

Comment: After scroll, the table won't stay !! See this : https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/s2xbf9d0/9/